# Included class - object in namespaces not "visible"

Tags: c++, namespaces

I need to create pointer to the object as class member and add one function. This object is stored in namespaces. So in my class:

```
//filename theObject.h

namespace namespaceA{
namespace namespaceB{
class theObject
{
    //content
};
}
}



//filename myClass.h
#include "theObject.h"

namespace namespaceA{
namespace otherNamespace{
class myClass
{
    //other members and functions
    void function(namespaceA::namespaceB::theObject* arg);
    namespaceA::namespaceB::theObject* m_obj;
};
}
}
```

Result - compilation errors:
error C3083: 'namespaceB': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
error C2039: 'theObject' : is not a member of 'namespaceA

Looks like theObject is not visible in myClass.h. I added

```
using namespace namespaceA::namespaceB;
```

just to check - I't also not visible.
I removed the new data from myClass and created global function:

```
void function(namespaceA::namespaceB::theObject* arg)
{
}
```

in myClass.cpp (which includes myClass.h only). Result - no errors. Did I miss something?

Comment: Your example compiles just fine in VS 2012. You need to build an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: To start with, you're missing include guards, which suggest to me that you may have some other basic error that prevents your headers from doing what they should.